# Updating to latest Windows 10 Insider Preview build does nothing, it restarts as normal

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, reboot, windows-10-preview

For the past two insider previews I've had to burn the ISO to a disk, and clean install to get it to install, otherwise it just boots up normally after the windows update 'restart' is pressed, or when setup is run from the ISO whilst logged in to windows.

Last time I just clean installed, but as it's happened again I'd prefer to find a fix.

Here are my two setup log files,

setuperr.log: https://gist.github.com/me4502/29eb825760fa82c8bf22

setupact.log: Too big to upload to gist/pastebin

I've tried my normal fixes or disconnecting all drives, and running it from the setup.exe on an ISO whilst logged in, but I always have the same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by booting up with the windows CD, erasing the bcd entry, and then recreating it. I'm assuming something must have been wrong with it, causing this issue.